# How to run htop or any other console based applications from 'alt+F2' command interface?

Tags: command-line, console

When I am pressing 'alt+F2', this command interface appears.

[image]

When I enter any non-console application like firefox, gnome-system-monitor, google-chrome etc and press enter, the application starts immediately. But when I am entering any console based application like htop or cmatrix, it is not starting.
I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS.

Do you guys know what wrong am I doing?

Comment: Try something like `gnome-terminal htop`, or whatever the default terminal emulator is in Gnome these days.

Comment: It will only open the terminal window not htop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism behind ***alt+F2*** assumes a graphical application program. I tested with

```
xterm -e htop
```

and it works for me. You can use another terminal window too. I think Ubuntu Gnome comes with ***gnome-terminal***, so it should work for you with

```
gnome-terminal -e htop
```

in the ***alt+F2*** window.